# How to make SSR render every state using Express or Vue router?

Tags: express, vue.js, vuejs2, state, vuex

I found a nice SSR (server side rendering) boilerplate with Vue in here :
https://github.com/csbun/vue2-ssr-example, right now it can only render pre-defined path from Express

and I need to associate the url path with state it generates,
like on this example,

[image]

It's already successfully fetch the data API,

[image]

But still I couldn't make it to work displaying state change to url.
Moreover, the project is complex with Vuex as state manager.

Comment: You do know we are not here to take in-depth looks into your project and spend 3 hours trying to figure out what is going on, while learning an obscure piece of software we will never use again right?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make it clear, It was included to give a clear picture, all I need is something like `app.use('/age/:state', function (req, res, next) {
  // get, set state to url
});`

Comment: you can get use `this.$router.push('/age/'+this.age)` after dispatching vuex action. Assuming age as `v-model`